# Why isn't the output match with my expected output?

Tags: python

My expected output is [0,7,6,0,0,0] why not?

```
lista = [2,7,6,3,4,2]
for i in lista:
    if i <= 4:
        lista[i] = 0

print(lista)
```

Comment: it should be `for i in range(len(lista))` and `if lista[i] <= 4`, and also try `lists = [0 for i in lista if i <= 0 else i]`

Comment: You forgot to describe what your code is supposed to do and why is that the expected output. Please read [ask] and please [edit] to update it.

Comment: You are indexing by elements of list, it's wrong. You should use:
```for i, element in enumerate(lista)```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're writing list[i]=0 then i here is index. Convert the whole loop in terms of index. Your code:

```
lista = [2,7,6,3,4,2]
for i in range(len(lista)):
    if lista[i] <= 4:
        lista[i] = 0

print(lista)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```py
lista = [2,7,6,3,4,2]
for i, item in enumerate(lista):
    if item <= 4:
        lista[i] = 0

print(lista)
```

Your code uses `lista[i] = 0`, which is not correct here. `i` is one of the items, not the index. By using `enumerate(lista)`, you can get the item and the index at the same time. In my opinion that's better than using `for i in range(0, len(lista))`.